# React-Bootstrap classes not overriding

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx, react-bootstrap

So my components directory looks like this:[image]

I have finished styling my MainNav component. Imported `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` in _costum.scss  and `@use 'costum';`  and I overrode necessary classes to style my nav. Now I tried to do the same to Footer component but it doesn't override styles it just uses properties that I gave in costum.scss to my navbar. I tried usting !important when I change **$navbar-padding-y: 1em** but it overrides my navbar style where its $navbar-padding-y: 6em; Is there other way then inline styling to override these properties?

Comment: Why are you overriding navbar variables at footer.scss?

Comment: @wuarmin I want to style my footer differently then my nav. So I copy classes from source bootstrap scss files like navbar.scss and i paste them into _changes.scss where I imported bootstrap, and I use that partial scss file with ' @ use changes' in footer.scss